# OpenVPN not showing easy-rsa

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

I did yum install openvpn in the guide then did the following:

```
mkdir -p /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys
cp -rf /usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/* /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
```

Fails. I get:

```
ls -la /usr/share/openvpn/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 31 21:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 64 root root 4096 Sep 20 20:26 ..
```

Where do I find the easy-rsa keys? I'm told in the guide I need to edit `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/vars` but I can't find the vars. What I did find was:

```
ls /usr/share/doc/openvpn-*/sample/sample-keys
ca.crt  ca.key  client.crt  client.key  dh1024.pem  pass.crt  pass.key  pkcs12.p12  README  server.crt  server.key
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy-rsa was bundled with **OpenVPN 2.2.x** and earlier. Since **OpenVPN 2.3.x** easy-rsa has to be separately installed from [here](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa/releases) or with a package manager.

**Location of easy-rsa up to OpenVPN 2.2.x:**

- `openvpn` installed from **rpm** or **deb**: `/usr/share/doc/packages/openvpn` or `/usr/share/doc/openvpn`
- `openvpn` installed from a **.tar.gz** file: in the top level directory of the expanded source tree.

**Location of easy-rsa from OpenVPN 2.3.x:**

- `easy-rsa` installed from **deb**: `/usr/share/easy-rsa`

Copy the `easy-rsa` directory to `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/` and generate your own set of keys and certificates as described in the [documentation](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html).

**Do not use the sample keys and certificates for a production environment.**